# What happen when a activity crashes

Tags: android, android-activity

I have some set of activities. Each are intended from some activity (flow do not matters ) lets say A to B to C activities.

If C crashes due to null pointer or any other exception. What happen to other previous activities. 
Will A and B both reload/recreated or only B reloads/recreated.

The another problem is when C crashes all the static variable are reinitialized. What is happening behind the scene

Answer (score 1):

It goes back to the previous state that was valid. So, lets say you oppened activity C and on create it shows error, it will throw you back to B activity. Now, if you open B activty and click on a button that opens C activity, and then the error appears, it will throw you back to the beggining of B activity.

Comment: That means on intent it pause the current state (at the time of Intent). and activity do not go any further.